# MVC AutoMapper models are different?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Will Automapper work, if I try to map a ModelMetadata that has only 5 properties and the Model.cs from the .edmx contains say 50 properties?

I basically created a ModelMetadata to customize the data annotations for five properties, but I was wondering if Automapper has problems mapping only 5 fields and not all 50 properties?

Will it just ignore the other 45 properties, if I only decided to update only 5 properties of a record to a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automapper gives you auto property mapping i.e if the property is the same on source and destination it will map. Others on the source and the destination that dont match will be ignored. You can also explicitly tell it how to map using ForMember e.g.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CalendarEvent, CalendarEventForm>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.EventDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EventDate.Date))   
.ForMember(dest => dest.EventHour, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EventDate.Hour))   
.ForMember(dest => dest.EventMinute, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EventDate.Minute));
```

The above example is pulled from the codeplex project site which fleshes this out properly [here](https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Projection)